# how to create dashed arrow in grease pencil

Tags: grease-pencil

I try to create a dashed arrow in Grease Pencil. I had limited success with a custom texture (rectangle with two squares, one in a color, the other transparent). My first trial was with Line type square, but that didn't work. However, now I need to add a solid fill arrow point, that preferably should rotate together with the arrow shaft.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Blender 3.0.0 you can use the [Dot Dash Modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/grease_pencil/modifiers/generate/dash.html) on a Grease Pencil object.

It works by toggling the visibility of points/segments along strokes, so you may need to subdivide your strokes to get enough points. Or dissolve some points to reduce the count if your points are too dense.

[image: Screenshot of Blender 3.0.0 showing a GreasePencil object in Edit mode with a Dot Dash modifier applied]